# Can I install 10.6 on a macbook 4,1 using a USB optical drive

Tags: macbook-pro, install, optical-drive

The superdrive in my late 2008 4,1 macbook has passed on but I need to upgrade the HDD with a larger one meaning a reinstall of 10.6 snow leopard.

Can I use an external optical drive to do this on such an old macbook or will I need to replace the internal?

If I can what key do I need to hold down at boot to access the USB optical drive.

Alternatively is there some way I can make a bootable USB, preferably without having to upgrade to Lion.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.

Holding <kbd>Option</kbd> on boot, will show you all the bootable possibilities.

Making a bootable USB is as easy as making a clean installation. Format the USB with the correct Mac Os X format, and then install as usual. [Here](http://macs.about.com/od/diyguidesprojects/ss/usbflash.htm) is a step-by-step guide, with lots of useful tips.

Comment: Used an external Samsung DVD drive, worked just fine.